# Llamar variable Global $wpdb afuera de la carpeta de plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

Cordial Saludo, alguien sabe si puedo llamar la variable global $wpdb afuera de la carpeta wp-content, si es asi como la llamo ya que ingreso global $wpdb y no me toma el llamado fuera de esta carpeta.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas llamar a núcleo de wordpress antes de llamar a $wpdb. Para ello debes añadir esto:

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';

//ahora $wpdb está dispoible aquí
```